# Ionic icon-generator issue

Tags: ionic-framework

In my ionic app i want ionic to generate my icons. So I have in my project directory a resources/android/icon.png with the size of 192x192.

The steps I did in the CLI:

```
cordova platform add android
ionic resources --icon
```

This way I get "resources/android/icon" directory. The problem is that the directory is empty.

```
ionic info
```

gives the following output:

[ionic info output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2iUx.png)

My config.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Test</name>
  <description>
      Test
  </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
    Your Name Here
  </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>    
</widget>
```

(If I remove my local icon.png and run `ionic platform add android` than it downloads the default icon and splash.)

So the question is why the icon directory is empty?

Comment: icons and splash screen are added to android when built

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.xml` you need to add splash and icon properties. Than you will see the changes in that folder 
Ex: Add these properties in your properties in your config.xml and see

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
  </platform>
```

Note:Use these command `ionic resources` and check it